# apche 2 show "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I install Apache 2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 and Chang sites-available with mysite config are

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sanjeet.jha@logicalindia.com

    DocumentRoot /data-sml/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /data-sml/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



</VirtualHost>
```

after that enable mysite by using

```
sudo a2ensite mysite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but it show

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Kindly Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have the correct permissions on the folder `/data-sml/www`.
Try setting it to `755`.

Command `sudo chmod 755 /data-sml/www`

Comment: I give permission but problem still have